# How to write a CGI file that would list the links for all the files or folders in a directory?

Tags: python, html, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I am new to this topic, but the goal is to access directories from a server based on the links. .htaccess will not work in my case as our server administrators configured the servers to not read .htaccess. So I was told I will have to go CGI route.

My python attempt which prints out directory listings on a console:

```html
import os

os.chdir("blah/blah")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    print files
```

Comment: Did you try to make some script? Show your code. What problem did you face?

Comment: So your admins will allow cgi to dish out anything but won't allow per directory .htaccess files? I think its time for an intervention.

Comment: @umka I wrote a simple python script that runs on console. But I need this in a web interface with the links. Thank you!

import os

os.chdir("blah/blah")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    print files

Comment: If you want to run this script as CGI, you have to change it's file permissions to executable (0755 for example), add a shebang to the first line: `#!/path/to/python`, and print a HTTP Content-Type header: `print('Content-Type: text/html\n\n')` before any other output.

Comment: @umka but even doing that will not give me a list of html href links to the contents in the directory.

Comment: If you see HTTP response from the script in browser, but don't see file list, it's most likely the script hasn't permissions to read the directory listing and you have to ask your server administrators to enable suexec or something like that to run your scripts under your user ID.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts has an example for doing cgi. In bowels of that script you could use use `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir` plus `os.path.isfile` to build an index using html <a> records.